# Let $G=[U,W]$ be a connected bipartite graph where $|U| = |W| \geq 2$

Tags: graph-theory

I need help with this problem, can you give me any ideas or something? please, thanks!

Let $G=[U,W]$ be a connected bipartite graph where $|U| = |W| \geq 2$. Show that if any two vertex in $U$ have differente degree, then $G$ has a perfect matching.

Comment: What is a perfect matching? Is it that you are able to flip U and W and get an isomorphic graph?

Answer (score 3):

**Disclaimer:**

I understand "any two vertex in $U$ have different degree" as $$\forall x,y \in U.\ \big(\deg(x) = \deg(y)\big) \implies (x = y). \tag{$\spadesuit$}$$

**Solution:**

Although you can do it using Hall's theorem, there's even simpler proof.

Observe, that $(\spadesuit)$ means that all the degrees are different. More precisely, because the degree of a vertex is between $1$ (the graph is connected) and $|W|=|U|$ (the graph is simple, there are no loops or doubled edges), from pigeon principle we know that degrees of vertices of $U$ are $1, 2, 3, \ldots, |U|$. Thus, we can take the vertex with the smallest degree (i.e., $1$) and match it. Then vertex with the second smallest degree (i.e., $2$) and also match it (it is possible, because it has at least one non-matched neighbor). And so on, until the last vertex that has degree $|U|$.
Therefore, we can match all the vertices in $|U|$ and because $|U| = |W|$, the matching is perfect.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Hi, you answer was really helpful, thank you so much, this gave me an idea and I'd like to know if it's right, what about induction on the macthing so here I go:

Let $G[U,W]$ be graph where $|U| = |W|$ and $deg(u) \neq deg(v) \forall u,v \in V(U)$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Recall Hall's theorem: the bipartite graph has a perfect matching iff for any subset $S$ of $U$ of size $k$, the neighborhood of $S$ has size $\geq k$ in $W$.

**Solution below**

> So if $S\subset U$, you know all vertices in $S$ have different degree, and moreover no vertex can have degree $0$ because the graph is connected. So in particular one of them will have degree $\geq |S|$. Now it follows that this one single vertex already has $\geq |S|$ neighbors in $W$.

Answer (score -1):

you answer was really helpful, thank you so much, this gave me an idea and I'd like to know if it's right, what about induction on the macthing so here I go:

Let $G[U,W]$ be graph where $k= |U| = |W| \geq 2$ and $deg(u) \neq deg(v) \forall u,v \in V(U)$, exits one perfect matching. 
if $k=2$ it's true, there's only one perfect matching;
if $k=3$ it's also true.
If we assume it's true for $k$

Let $|U| = |W| = k+1$, Let $v \in V(U)$  where $deg(v) = k+1$ and Let $u \in V(W) $ where $N(u) = {v}$. Now Let $H[U', W'] = G - v -u $ now $|U'|  |W´| = k$ this has one perfect matching because hypothesis . Then $G$ has one perfect matching the one contain in $H + vu$ where $uv \in E(G)$ since $v$ is the only neighbour   of $u$ they can match together and we know that the rest of vertex are already matched.

is this ok?

Comment: Your reasoning is not correct, because you didn't specified which vertex $u$ you remove, and you might remove one that is connected to some other vertex. On the other hand if you pick $u$ correctly, then your reasoning could be correct.

Comment: Well I thought that as any vertex in $U$ has a differente degree then there's is only one vertex $u$ where for $u$ vertex $v$ is its only neighbour , or how could I select it correctly?

Comment: Consider: $V=\{1,2,3, a, b, c\}$, $E=\{(1,a), (2,b),(2,c), (3,a),(3,b),(3,c)\}$.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I've been thinking, and what if $u$ is the vertex where all its neighbours must have degree $\geq \frac{deg(v)}{2}$ or the one who only has a $v$ as it's neighbour, being this last one the first option for consideration, is it too confusing?

Comment: I think it also wouldn't solve the problem. The main issue with your idea is that you want to pick $u$ first. A better approach would be to first apply the induction hypothesis and then set $u$ to be any neighbor that was left unmatched. To make it work, change also the hypothesis, so that it is not about perfect matching, but rather $U$-saturating matching (or matching of size $|U|$), so that it works when the sides are of non-equal size.